# Semaphores as a diamond

Tags: c++, algorithm, semaphore

My homework was to perform waits and signals on an array of semaphores in a diamond pattern.

Here is the pattern:

```
    08
  06  07  
03  04  05
  01  02
    00

Thread #08 cannot join the diamond until threads #06 and #07 are both in position.
Thread #07 cannot join until threads #04 and #05 are both in position.
Thread #06 cannot join until threads #03 and #04 are both in position. and so on...
```

So far my thinking has resulted in the following ugly algorithm:

```
   if (me==0) {
       wait_sem (tCount[1]) ;
       wait_sem (tCount[2]) ;
       signal_sem (tCount[0]) ;
   }
   if (me==1) {
       wait_sem (tCount[3]) ;
       wait_sem (tCount[4]) ;
   }
   if (me==2) {
       wait_sem (tCount[4]) ;
       wait_sem (tCount[5]) ;
   }
   if (me==3) {
       wait_sem (tCount[6]) ;
   }
   if (me==4) {
       wait_sem (tCount[6]) ;
       wait_sem (tCount[7]) ;
   }
   if (me==5) {
       wait_sem (tCount[7]) ;
   }
   if (me==6) {
       wait_sem (tCount[8]) ;
   }
   if (me==7) {
       wait_sem (tCount[8]) ;
   }
```

Is there a cleaner method of doing this? I heard `switch` but I have never used it before so if anyone suggests it please provide me with an explanation and or example. Thanks a lot for all input.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just take a really simple approach, where you keep your semaphores in a global array (or simply just accessible to your threads).  You can set up a list of dependencies like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> thread_depends = {
    { },      // 0
    { 0 },    // 1
    { 0 },    // 2
    { 1 },    // 3
    { 1, 2 }, // 4
    { 2 },    // 5
    { 3, 4 }, // 6
    { 4, 5 }, // 7
    { 6, 7 }, // 8
};
```

Now, each thread just needs to wait on everything in `thread_depends[me]`:

```
const auto & dep = thread_depends[me];
std::for_each( dep.begin(), dep.end(), [&tCount](int who){ wait_sem( tCount[who] ); } );
signal_sem( tCount[me] );
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't duplicate the logic of what to do for each case.  Instead, you're just representing the dependencies, and you only have one piece of code that does the actual work.  This means less chance of making a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Quick question, would I include this code in the function involving the algorithm, or should I put some of it to be globally accessed?

Comment: It's hard to give a quick answer to that.

Comment: Ok, I understand. I'll play with it a bit then. Thanks a ton

Comment: One thing I think I should point out is that if the concepts I'm using here (C++11 initializer lists, `<algorithm>`, iterators, and lambdas) are completely new to you, it might be very obvious to your teacher that your homework answer was not written by you. ;)

Comment: right of course I'll probably write this down and speak with him about it to get a better understanding :)

Comment: How about I propose this challenge: Take what I've written, figure out how it works, and write it without using anything from the standard library.  _i.e._ using only arrays and loops (no vectors, lambdas, _etc_).  I answered this way on purpose because I knew it would not be a believable homework answer if you just copied it down.  So if you can make it more your own, then you will have learned quite a lot by asking this question.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128119/discussion-between-junikin-and-paddy).

Answer (score 1):

This solution is only to show how it could be done with case, there are better implementations for this problem!

Switch is better than if's/else because it works as a jump, when if's will need to test all conditions until its satisfied (if0, if1, if2...), the switch will directly to the right case.

```
switch(me)
{
    case 0:
        wait_sem(tCount[1]);
        wait_sem(tCount[2]);
        signal_sem(tCount[me]);
        break;
    case 1:
        wait_sem(tCount[3]) ;
        wait_sem(tCount[4]) ;
        signal_sem(tCount[me]);
        break;
    case 2:
        wait_sem(tCount[4]);
        wait_sem(tCount[5]);
        signal_sem(tCount[me]);
        break;
    case 3:
        wait_sem(tCount[6]);
        signal_sem(tCount[me]);
        break;
    case 4:
       wait_sem(tCount[6]);
       wait_sem(tCount[7]);
       signal_sem(tCount[me]);
       break;
    case 5:
       wait_sem(tCount[7]);
       signal_sem(tCount[me]);
       break;
    case 6:
       wait_sem(tCount[8]);
       signal_sem(tCount[me]);
       break;
    case 7:
       wait_sem(tCount[8]);
       signal_sem(tCount[me]);
       break;
    case 8:
       signal_sem(tCount[me]);
       break;
}
```